# Make Angular inline global styles

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

How do I configure Angular 2 to inline/inject global styles into a `<style>` tag in `<head>`?

Running `ng new site` and then `ng serve --prod` serves up a page with a `<link href="styles.x.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` tag in `<head>`. Not inlined.

If I use `ng serve --prod --extract-css=false` then the styles are packed into a `styles.x.bundle.js` file which is loaded via a `<script>` tag at the end. Still not inlined.

But I want the CSS to be inlined/injected directly into the `<head>`.

---

Edit: Note I would still like to maintain a separate styles file (so I have the option of using SASS).

Comment: would worth mentioning the reason you want it, I'd guess to avoid [flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) on your initial `loading...`  screen

Comment: @Stavm Yes, that's correct. I'd like to speed up initial page load (by reducing the number of needed HTTP requests) without the initial flash as you put it.

Answer (score -2):

After tinkering with some of the build configs, manage to resolve this by doing the following:

1. set the `extractCss` value to `false` within your production build config in `angular.json`

**OR**, just run the command below:

```
ng config "projects.site.architect.build.configurations.production.extractCss" false
```

Then serve using the production flag

```
ng s --prod
```

I have only tested this with the following file: `src/app/styles.css`, so not sure if this would output ALL styles as inline...

But as per OP, these global styles are inlined

Comment: -1 I believe this is the option that produces what I was talking about when I said "the styles are packed into a styles.x.bundle.js file which is loaded via a <script> tag at the end. Still not inlined." I'm looking for styles "inlined/injected directly into the <head>". Thanks, though!

Comment: No offense matt, but I did test this and it worked. Inline styles within the style tag within the head tag. Would you mind giving it a try?

Comment: I did as well. I was trying to use a soft tone when I said "I believe" :)

Comment: Here I'll post my repro of your instructions along with final output. One moment...

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/matthew-a-thomas/so-answer-55574294-3063273 And the contents of the `dist` directory after `ng build --prod`: https://github.com/matthew-a-thomas/so-answer-55574294-3063273/raw/master/Contents%20of%20dist%20directory%20after%20ng%20build%20prod.zip

Comment: Hi again, so really wanna make sure i understand you correctly... had a look at your repo, executed the commands above, and the following resulted... https://imgur.com/a/W8WlZdM . Looks like it worked?! Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Interesting. I'll take away the -1, but to +1 and accept as the answer I'd like to be able to reproduce your results. Can you link to your code?

Comment: Well, I cannot change my vote on your answer until it is edited (SO won't let me). Maybe you could post a link to your full code in your answer?

Comment: Oh oh oh, I know why we can't agree. You're looking at Chrome Dev Tools. That's what JavaScript (our little Angular app) has mutated the DOM into. Look instead at the raw source of the `index.html` file that Angular generates. That's what I'm talking about

Comment: ah, ok, cool cool cool... yeah, we're on the same wavelength. Unfortunately don't think there is a way to do that, UNLESS!!!! you manually link the stylesheet... i'll post an update, which probably doesn't suit your needs though :(

Comment: don't stress about the votes for now. this is what i ran, `ng build --prod` to produce what your question was referring to. Then i ran the following, `ng config "projects.site.architect.build.configurations.production.extractCss" true && ng s --prod` to produce the inline styles